# How to choose certain rows and certain column from a group of rows and covert them into one row and then bind them with the data frame?

Tags: r, vectorization

How to choose certain rows and certain column from a group of rows and covert them into one row and then bind them with the data frame?

Please see the `Example df`, there are Group 1 and Group 2, each Group has 6 rows.

`1st` row of the Group, choose Row 1, 2 and 3 of that Group of `Weight` & `Height` & `Volume` and convert them into one row and bind them to the data frame.

`2nd` row of the Group, choose Row 1, 2 and 3 of that Group of `Weight` & `Height` & `Volume` and convert them into one row and bind them to the data frame.

`3rd` row of the Group,  choose Row 2, 3 and 4 of that Group of `Weight` & `Height` & `Volume` and convert them into one row and bind them to the data frame.

`4th` row of the Group,  choose Row 3, 4 and 5 of that Group of `Weight` & `Height` & `Volume` and convert them into one row and bind them to the data frame.

`5th` row of the Group,  choose Row 4, 5 and 6 of that Group of `Weight` & `Height` & `Volume` and convert them into one row and bind them to the data frame.

`6th` row of the Group,  choose Row 4, 5 and 6 of that Group of `Weight` & `Height` & `Volume` and convert them into one row and bind them to the data frame.

And will become something like the `Expected Outcome`.
How to achieve this the vectorize way?

**Update:** I have got what I want to achieve but is there a more efficient approach ?

```
# create a column to store the row indexes 
df$row = rownames(df)
# choose the first row of every group, and store the indexes into "first"
library(plyr)
df$V1 = 0
df$V2 = 0
df$V3 = 0
first = ddply(df, .(Group), function(x) x[ 1 , ])$row 
second= ddply(df, .(Group), function(x) x[ 2 , ])$row 
third = ddply(df, .(Group), function(x) x[ 3 , ])$row 
df$V1[first] = df$Weight[first]
df$V2[first] = df$Height[first]
df$V3[first] = df$Volume[first]

#....so on and do the rest of the V4~6
```

**Example df**

```
    Weight Height Volume Group   
 1:   11    12      17     1
 2:   25    17      19     1
 3:   29    25      20     1
 4:   34    35      27     1
 5:   39    36      31     1
 6:   18    20      37     1
 7:    9    12       4     2
 8:   10    33       7     2
 9:   18    25      19     2
10:   26    19      20     2
11:   27    22      25     2
12:   38    59      36     2
```

**Expected Outcome**

```
    Weight Height Volume Group   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9
 1:   11    12      17     1     11 12 17 29 25 20 29 25 20 
 2:   25    17      19     1     11 12 17 29 25 20 29 25 20 
 3:   29    25      20     1     25 17 19 29 25 20 34 35 27
 4:   34    35      27     1     29 25 20 34 35 27 39 36 31
 5:   39    36      31     1     34 35 27 39 36 31 18 20 37
 6:   18    20      37     1     34 35 27 39 36 31 18 20 37
 7:    9    12       4     2      9 12  4 10 33  7 18 25 19
 8:   10    33       7     2      9 12  4 10 33  7 18 25 19
 9:   18    25      19     2     10 33  7 18 25 19 26 19 20
10:   26    19      20     2     18 25 19 26 19 20 27 22 25
11:   27    22      25     2     26 19 20 27 22 25 38 59 36
12:   38    59      36     2     26 19 20 27 22 25 38 59 36
```

Comment: What have you tried, even if non-vectorized?

Comment: Yes I have tried.